# Unity - Vector3.Reflect not reflecting correctly

Tags: unity, game-design

I resolved the question on how to draw a line, so here is the result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvc9yr3jjbqdv7r/dc.jpg?dl=0

So, now I want to create a line that shows the possible bounce off the wall (and the other ball).

Some suggested I use the Reflect method but it did not work, here is how I implemented it, script is attached to the white que ball:

```
//
        Ray ray2 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit2;

        //
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray2, out hit2, 100.0f)){





            //position of white wall
            Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
            //cliked position, translated to the table plane
            Vector3 clickPos2 = new Vector3(hit2.point.x, hit2.point.y, transform.position.z);
             //get direction from ball to clicked position
            Vector3 direction = Direction (clickPos2 - startPos);

              //so I simply should do I reflect, it gives me a bit odd results
            Vector3 reflectDir = Vector3.Reflect(direction, hit2.normal);


            //finally im drawing the line
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, startPos);

            Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(direction) * 100;
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, forward);

              //reflection?
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(2, hit2.point);

            lineRenderer.SetPosition(3, reflectDir);
```

Here is what this code gives me:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dfb3vyqmbknzes/gb.jpg?dl=0

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Mirza

Comment: Both Dropbox links are actually dead.

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure, because your Dropbox link is dead,
  but I think your error is in the last line of your code. 
The lineRenderer connect Points in space and you need to convert your direction to a point.By adding a starting vector to your direction.

```
lineRenderer.SetPosition(3, reflectDir+hit2.point);
```

Comment: Looks like a good guess to me.